# How to sum two times in Java, using LocalTime?

Tags: java, java-8, sum, localtime

Example:

```
LocalTime time1 = LocalTime.of(12, 30);
LocalTime time2 = LocalTime.of(8, 30);
time1 + time2   // Doesn't work.
time1.plus(time2)   // Doesn't work.
```

I want to get the sum of the two times (12:30 + 8:30 = 21:00) in the format of (hours:minutes).

Any other suggestions?

Comment: What do you expect when adding up two times?

Comment: Do you just want to add the hours and mins from time2 to time1?

Comment: You can add together `Duration` objects - they represent an amount of time. You can add a `Duration` to a `LocalDate`. You cannot add two dates - it makes absolutely no sense...

Comment: @Pshemo A `LocalTime` is not a date, it's a time-of-day (hour, minute, second).

Comment: @Jesper Oh, you are right, I misread it as LocalDate. Anyway problem still is similar: what result OP expects and why?

Answer (score 11):

You are trying to add two `LocalTime` variables.  This is wrong as a concept.  Your time2 should not be a `LocalTime`, it should be a `Duration`.  A duration added to a time gives you another time.  A time subtracted from a time gives you a duration.  It is all nice and logical.  Adding two times together is not.

It is possible with some hacking to convert your time to a duration, but I would strongly advise against that.  Instead, restructure your code so that time2 is a `Duration` in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following...

```
LocalTime t1 = LocalTime.of(9, 0);  // 09:00
LocalTime t2 = LocalTime.of(2, 30); // 02:30
LocalTime total = t1.plusHours(t2.getHour())
                    .plusMinutes(t2.getMinute());  // 11:30
```

Answer (score 1):

<s>The answer of Mike Nakis does not true.</s>

The above sentence of mine doesn't true. I have checked and only Java 8 has `LocalTime.of` so Mike Nakis's answer is perfectly true. Please see his answer.

[This section still keep. in case `LocalTime` in joda library ]

I will explain:

> **A duration** in Joda-Time represents a duration of time measured in milliseconds. The duration is often obtained from an interval. i.e. we
>   can subtract start from end of an interval to derive a duration.
>
> **A period** in Joda-Time represents a period of time defined in terms of fields, for example, 3 years 5 months 2 days and 7 hours. This
>   differs from a duration in that it is inexact in terms of
>   milliseconds. A period can only be resolved to an exact number of
>   milliseconds by specifying the instant (including chronology and time
>   zone) it is relative to. e.g. consider the period of 1 year, if we add
>   this to January 1st we will always arrive at the next January 1st but
>   the duration will depend on whether the intervening year is a leap
>   year or not.

`LocalTime` is an immutable time class representing a time *without a time zone*. So, base on above definition, period is suitable for you adding time to `LocalTime`. In fact, API has proved this:

```
LocalTime localTime = new LocalTime(10, 30);
Duration d = new Duration(1, 0);
Period p = new Period(1, 0);
LocalTime newLocalTime = localTime.plus(d); // COMPILE ERROR
LocalTime newLocalTime = localTime.plus(p); // SUCCESS
```

Comment: @MikeNakis I'm sorry for all. I have upvoted again your answer (that I need edit so I can upvote again, haha). I'm sorry that I don't see carefully original question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the method sum()

```
LocalTime time1 = LocalTime.of(12, 30);
LocalTime time2 = LocalTime.of(8, 30);
Integer hour1 = time1.getHour();
Integer hour2 = time2.getHour();
Integer minute1 = time1.getMinute();
Integer minute2 = time2.getMinute();

Integer first = Integer.sum(hour1,hour2);
Integer second = Integer.sum(minute1,minute2);

System.out.println("The time is "+ first + " : " + second);
```

It must work

Answer (score 0):

```
LocalTime t1 = LocalTime.parse('03:33:24')
LocalTime t2 = LocalTime.parse('03:13:41')

t1.plusHours(t2.hour)
  .plusMinutes(t2.minute)
  .plusSeconds(t2.second)
  .plusNanos(t2.nano)
```